# Is it possible for JIT inlining to inline my code into some .NET runtime assembly code?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, jit

I'd like to understand how ubiquitous JIT inlining can be.

Suppose in my code I call some function from say `System.IO` assembly and pass a callback reference to a function implemented in my code for being called from inside that `System.IO` function. In my function there's `GetCallingAssembly()` call. So if my callback gets inlined into `System.IO` the call to `GetCallingAssembly()` that originally was in my code and was intended to say the "current" method is called from inside `System.IO` will say that it now is called from inside my code.

Is such inlining possible or are .NET runtime assemblies treated differently so that JIT inlining of user code into .NET runtime code is not allowed?

Comment: How would a delegate callback ever get inlined to the callback-invoker? I'm not sure that makes sense...? My understanding is that inlining is limited to scenarios where the code to be invoked is **provable** - i.e. a static call, or a virtual-call to a non-virtual method.

Comment: @Mark Gravel: Why couldn't it if that is know to be the only invokation of the callback invoker in the whole program?

Comment: I *suspect* that is more effort to understand than the JIT is going to ever do, especially since reflection / meta-programming exists (meaning: new callers could exist later)

Comment: Could you have picked an odder example for an assembly? I was going to say that it doesn't exist - then I discovered that it *does* exist under v4.0, but so far as I can see, it purely forwards types back to mscorlib - and so far as I'm aware, those types have always existed in mscorlib. Hmmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely assume the callback will not be inlined.  .NET Framework assemblies are always pre-jitted by ngen.exe at install time, there's no option to alter that code afterwards.  Furthermore, callbacks through a delegate are never inlined even if the jitter optimizer could deduce what the delegate's target method might be.